# In TYPO3 6.x, how to rewrite file links URLs

Tags: url-rewriting, typo3

With FAL in TYPO3 6.x, it should probably be possible to rewrite download links, so that the notorious "fileadmin" won't appear in the downloadable file's URL.

But how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With FAL you can easily create a `File storage` that points to folder residing not only in `fileadmin` dir, so you can create ie.: `docs` folder in the root folder and then add the `File storage` on page with UID 0.

Comment: Can I add another `file storage` on top of an existing `file storage`? I had unthinkingly set `fileadmin/editors/public` as one file storage. Now I noticed we still have the long, ugly `fileadmin` path. I tried to add a second storage, called `public` and told it to point it to the same above folder. It works in the backend, but in the frontend, `mydomain.com/public/file.pdf` leads to nothing but an error.